# passing argument 1 of 'objectAtIndex:' makes integer from pointer without a cast

Tags: iphone

The application crashes when I select the data from the picker.

```
NSString *labl=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[self.datePicker selectedRowInComponent:0]];
NSString *strPrintRepeat = (NSString *)[years objectAtIndex:labl];
```

Answer (score 2):

You know you are passing `NSString` to objectAtIndex  `[years objectAtIndex:labl];` . Here labl is a string not `integer` value.So you need to do either convert this string into int value or do this.

```
NSString *strPrintRepeat = (NSString *)[years objectAtIndex:[self.datePicker selectedRowInComponent:0]];
```

Comment: Welcome dear..and if you got your solution then accept this answer.

Answer (score 1):

try with bellow Line of code:-

objectAtIndex haveing `NSUInteger` parameter define method in Array.h file:-

[image]

please study apple provided Doc about it :-

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html

and you can use your Method like bellow:-

```
NSString *strPrintRepeat = (NSString *)[years objectAtIndex:[labl intValue]];
```